How does “Monkey Man” incorporate elements of Hindu mythology?
In the 2024 film Monkey Man, I was really intrigued by how the protagonist, the "Kid" (played by Dev Patel), who goes by the name "the Beast" in an underground fighting ring, seems to have modeled his whole persona—the titular “Monkey Man"—on the Hindu god Hanuman.
As the film reveals, when the Kid was little, his mother used to tell him all these stories about Hanuman. And in the film, you can kind of see how those tales stuck with him and ultimately inspired his gritty "Beast" alter ego that he takes on to survive in Tiger's sketchy bare-knuckle fight club.
As someone with limited knowledge of Hindu mythology, I am curious to know the parallels or connections between the film's narrative and characters and the tales of Hanuman specifically, or Hindu mythology in general.
Are there any specific plot points, character arcs, or thematic overlaps that parallel or echo elements from the stories of Hanuman or other Hindu mythological tales? If so, I would greatly appreciate insights into these connections, particularly those pertaining to the struggles and journey of the Kid.

I'm inclined to think that this question is a little too broad for M&TV. Not DV or CV but just my impression at first glance.

@Paulie_D From what I can tell, the film's parallels to Hindu mythology are not that extensive, so I think a focused answer could cover it. That said, if anyone has suggestions on how to narrow it down while still addressing the core of the question, I'm all ears.
